# How to prove an Android device is hacked? Retrieving logs from recovery booting

Tags: recovery-mode, malware, logging, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I'm having trouble with my new branded Vodafone Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge.

[image: Sockstat screenshot]

How can I get a copy to the full logs (and other files), without rooting, for places I do not have the required access? I can read the logs in recovery booting, but how can I transfer digital copies of these logs as text to for example my email?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a good file explorer app for your device. The link in a good one for non-rooted devices and it's free. Also, you can remote access your file system on another device. I don't think it will be in real-time, but a way to monitor or link to someone that can help you with this.

I would also hook your device up to a computer if you have access and make sure you have all your settings right on your device (refer to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgRlVBhvBoM)). At the very least, copy the entire file system. Even if you cannot make heads or tales of it, someone can.

I would also download a system cleaner app (after copying the files) like [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm). Clean up your cache, history, passwords, etc. Then change all passwords. Run cleaner again. Re-hook up to the computer make another copy of everything save to compare later. Extreme, factory reset your device in recovery if you can. Re-setup your device the way you like it, even the exact same way through your Google account, and make another copy. Then make a copy every now and then to see to have on file.

Ideally, I would root your system for the benefits of having some third-party APKs.

Answer (score 0):

If the attacker has control of your device, look for Bluetooth modules loaded in the kernel, you will see it in recovery logs.

If they have control, you can't root it, not even with Odin unless you build or buy a signal jammer. Then you can do `adb pull` and that might give you what you are looking for.

There is no app or malware anything, no security of any kind that will help you. You will have to decompile the kernel yourself and or `lsmod` and remove what shouldn't be there.

I've dealt with this for 12 years. My ex-sociopath still takes over every device I get and destroys them remotely. I have a BLE network hidden somewhere that serves as a network where all my devices stream audio and video and she somehow uses my Raspberry Pi to assist in this. 3 iPhones 4 Android devices, iMac, and smart TVs all play a role.